# Network Printing From Ubuntu to Windows

Tags: networking, printing, 64-bit, 17.04, sharing

What is the procedure to do network printing from Ubuntu? The printer is connected to a system running Windows OS(Host System -**Windows 7 (32-bit)**). From Guest Systems running Windows OS, the network printing is possible. How to do the same from a Guest System running Ubuntu?

- The version of Ubuntu : **Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit**.
- Printer : **Canon Imageclass MF4320d**.

***Update***

- File sharing using samba from ubuntu to windows is working.

[image]

- In printer settings this printer is not seen.

Comment: Go to System Settings, Printers, Add Printer, Select Device: Windows Printer via SAMBA, enter Windows Print Server details.

Comment: @konrad Windows printer via samba option is not there

Comment: The printer is Imageclass MF4320d from Canon.